# Parse .net JSON string in MVC view using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string temp =  this.someService.GetAllLists();
    return View((object)temp);
}
```

The variable temp is string in JSON format. I used standard JavaScriptSerializer and JsonConvert by Newtonsoft.

Is there any way to parse this string in view to make javascript objects?

I tried to use JSON.parse, but it shows the error 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data'

Comment: Are you using any front end frameworks? Also could you post the output so we can see it?

Comment: Post the actual javascript code and the content of temp string

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the content of the string. Please post the actual JSON string that it doesn't like

Comment: Here is example of JSON string:
[{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"P.1 - English\"}]
Bellow answer helped to solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use viewbag in your action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string temp =  this.someService.GetAllLists();
    ViewBag.Lists = temp;
    return View();
}
```

In your js, get the viewbag data, replace the &quot character which is present in the json string with ", parse the string to json and assign it to js variable

```
var data = '@ViewBag.Lists';
var jsObj = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```